# How to prevent Beamer from changing the normal text color when I change the footnote color?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, color

When I change the footnote color in Beamer using `\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}`, I end up also inadvertently changing the normal text color on all other slides. To make things even stranger, the normal text is correct only on slides that have footnotes. The following example demonstrates my problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
It seems like adding a footnote\footnote{Like this} will cause the normal text of subsequent slides to inherit the footnote's color.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
See? This text is now blue.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Invoking another footnote\footnote{like this} will cause the fonts to return to normal color, at least for this slide.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    But this text will again be blue (the color of the footnotes)!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm using MacTex 2010.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in beamer. You should report it at https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/ so that it will hopefully get resolved in the next version.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like a bug ... but this should help

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{footnotemark}{fg=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
\parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark} 
  \textcolor{blue}{\insertfootnotetext}\par}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it local per frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%{\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}
It seems like adding a footnote\footnote{Like this} will cause the normal text of subsequent slides to inherit the footnote's color.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
See? This text is now blue.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=blue}
Invoking another footnote\footnote{like this} will cause the fonts to return to normal color, at least for this slide.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    But this text will again be blue (the color of the footnotes)!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... redefine the template

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=green} % the mark (1, 2, ...)
\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{\mbox{ \insertfootnotemark \textcolor{red}{ \insertfootnotetext}}} 
%  local use of a color (its not so beamer like but works)

\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{One}

some text in black
 \footnote{don´t use red!}
red and green footnote

}

\frame{
\frametitle{Two}

not red

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: works only for short footnotes ... `\mbox` doesn't allow a linebreak

Comment: Sure you could use `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{    \strut \insertfootnotemark \textcolor{red}{ \insertfootnotetext}}` instead.